# autoHeight owl-carousel 2

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I want the items to take 100% of the height of the container.
If I give a height to the element in px, it works perfect, but I want the height to be 100%. In the desktop version, if I can put a value in px, but in the mobile, I need it to take 100% of the height.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  animateOut: 'fadeOut',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 4000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  autoHeight:true
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  overflod: hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.csss">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">

<div class="content">
  <div class="fadeOut owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving height in pixels you can define in vh (View-port-height) as:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  animateOut: 'fadeOut',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 4000,
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  autoHeight:true
});
```

```css
.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  overflod: hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.csss">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">

<div class="content">
  <div class="fadeOut owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded owl-drag">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item yellow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```